# Cursors in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-cursor

I am reading a book for stored procedures and they are explaining cursors inside it but i didn't happen to find a decent use for Cursors or a rule scenario where Cursor usage is a must.

Comment: Godo thing you didn't find a sample! You should **avoid cursors** at all costs - they're evil monstrosities, and more than 90% of the time, they're not neeed, nor are they really useful. Do your stuff **in a set-based manner** - much better approach than the **Row-by-agonizing-Row** approach used in cursors....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cursors when you want to loop on a result set from a select statement to do something with each row. It is like the foreach in any programming language.

Comment: You *can* - but you should not. Ever.

Comment: then why do i need to do that ? cant  i just filter the result in the query and have what i need exactly inside the select statement .....